# how to integrate atom payment gateway in PHP

Tags: php, yii, payment-gateway

I am using ATOM payment gateway and YII framework. I am using following code & i am not getting response here $returnData = curl_exec($ch); its returning empty.

Please tell how can i come over it. is ther any tutorials for this integration.

```
 $url = ‘http://203.114.240.77/paynetz/epi/fts';// test bed URL
 $port = 80;
 $atom_prod_id = “NSE”;
// code to generate token
 $param =   "&login=".$userid."&pass=".$password."&ttype=NBFundTransfer&prodid=".$atom_prod_id."&amt=".$amount."&txncurr=INR&txnscamt=0&clientcode=".$clientcode."&txnid=".$invoiceid."&date=".$today."&custacc=12345";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
$returnData = curl_exec($ch);
 // Check if any error occured
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
echo ‘Curl error: ‘ . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($returnData);
$final_url = $xmlObj->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->url;
// eof code to generate token
// code to generate form action
$param = “”;
$param .= “&ttype=NBFundTransfer”;
$param .= “&tempTxnId=”.$xmlObj->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param[1];
$param .= “&token=”.$xmlObj->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param[2];
$param .= “&txnStage=1″;
$url = $url.”?”.$param;
// eof code to generate form action
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the http response code. Are you expecting any data to be returned? You're posting data, maybe the response-body should be empty?

Please add the code below to check for the http status code.

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo $info["http_code"];
```

Comment: got this "Curl error: Empty reply from server0"  @Emile Bons

Comment: You start `$param` with a &. I doubt whether that's correct.